# Creating tables in MySQL based on the names of the columns in another table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table with ~133M rows and 16 columns. I want to create 14 tables on another database on the same server for each of columns 3-16 (columns 1 and 2 are `` `id` `` and `` `timestamp` `` which will be in the final 14 tables as well but won't have their own table), where each table will have the name of the original column. Is this possible to do exclusively with an SQL script? It seems logical to me that this would be the preferred, and fastest way to do it.

Currently, I have a Python script that "works" by parsing the CSV dump of the original table (testing with 50 rows), creating new tables, and adding the associated values, but it is very slow (I estimated almost 1 year to transfer all 133M rows, which is obviously not acceptable). This is my first time using SQL in any capacity, and I'm certain that my code can be sped up, but I'm not sure how because of my unfamiliarity with SQL. The big SQL string command in the middle was copied from some other code in our codebase. I've tried using transactions as seen below, but it didn't seem to have any significant effect on the speed.

```
import re
import mysql.connector
import time

# option flags
debug = False  # prints out information during runtime
timing = True  # times the execution time of the program

# save start time for timing. won't be used later if timing is false
start_time = time.time()

# open file for reading
path = 'test_vaisala_sql.csv'
file = open(path, 'r')

# read in column values
column_str = file.readline().strip()
columns = re.split(',vaisala_|,', column_str)  # parse columns with regex to remove commas and vasiala_
if debug:
    print(columns)

# open connection to MySQL server
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='<redacted>',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='measurements')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# create the table in the MySQL database if it doesn't already exist
for i in range(2, len(columns)):
    table_name = 'vaisala2_' + columns[i]
    sql_command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + \
                  table_name + "(`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " \
                               "`timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " \
                               "`milliseconds` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', " \
                               "`value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, " \
                               "PRIMARY KEY (`id`), " \
                               "UNIQUE KEY `milliseconds` (`milliseconds`)" \
                               "COMMENT 'Eliminates duplicate millisecond values', " \
                               "KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)) " \
                               "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"

    if debug:
        print("Creating table", table_name, "in database")

    cursor.execute(sql_command)

# read in rest of lines in CSV file
for line in file.readlines():
    cursor.execute("START TRANSACTION;")
    line = line.strip()
    values = re.split(',"|",|,', line)  # regex split along commas, or commas and quotes
    if debug:
        print(values)

    # iterate of each data column. Starts at 2 to eliminate `id` and `timestamp`
    for i in range(2, len(columns)):
        table_name = "vaisala2_" + columns[i]
        timestamp = values[1]

        # translate timestamp back to epoch time
        try:
            pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(timestamp, pattern)))
            milliseconds = epoch * 1000  # convert seconds to ms
        except ValueError:  # errors default to 0
            milliseconds = 0

        value = values[i]

        # generate SQL command to insert data into destination table
        sql_command = "INSERT IGNORE INTO {} VALUES (NULL,'{}',{},'{}');".format(table_name, timestamp,
                                                                                 milliseconds, value)
        if debug:
            print(sql_command)

        cursor.execute(sql_command)
cnx.commit()  # commits changes in destination MySQL server

# print total execution time
if timing:
    print("Completed in %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This doesn't need to be incredibly optimized; it's perfectly acceptable if the machine has to run for a few days in order to do it. But 1 year is far too long.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Strawberry 8.0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table from a `SELECT` like:

```
CREATE TABLE <other database name>.<column name>
             AS
             SELECT <column name>
                    FROM <original database name>.<table name>;
```

(Replace the `<...>` with your actual object names or extend it with other columns or a `WHERE` clause or ...)

That will also insert the data from the query into the new table. And it's probably the fastest way.

You could use dynamic SQL and information from the catalog (namely [`information_schema.columns`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html)) to create the `CREATE` statements or create them manually, which is annoying but acceptable for 14 columns I guess.

Answer (score 1):

When using scripts to talk to databases you want to minimise the number of messages that are sent as each message creates a further delay on your execution time. Currently, it looks as if you are sending (by your approximation) 133 million messages, and thus, slowing down your script 133 million times. A simple optimisation would be to parse your spreadsheet and split the data into the tables (either in memory or saving them to disk) and only then send the data to the new DB.

As you hinted, it's much quicker to write an SQL script to redistribute the data.